# How to stop endless loop when calling and writing an array from a static method

Tags: java

Java Novice:

I am practicing this stuff: How do I stop the endless loop when calling the array from the method into the main method?

```
public static String[] ArrayColors() {
    String MyColors[] = { "Red", "Blue", "Green"};
    return MyColors;
}

public static String WriteArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (String lines : ArrayColors()) {

            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                lines = lines.replace("Red", "Blood");
                break;
            case 1:
                lines = lines.replace("Blue", "Ocean");
                break;
            case 2:
                lines = lines.replace("Green", "Giant");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(lines);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return WriteArray().toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(WriteArray());
}
```

Comment: Use lowercase starting chars for method names, and when you get an infinite loop, print some debug info.

Comment: Don't call `WriteArray()` recursively. That's making the infinite loop.

Comment: Easiest way to stop it is to not start it.

Comment: Funny, I like that one. :)

Comment: Well, it's very true.

Comment: Calling toString() on a String is also a bit weird. They even use an exclamation mark in that part of the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString()).

Comment: LOL. Correct, although the method must necessarily be there, to comply with the `CharSequence` API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recursive loop is caused by the statement

```
return WriteArray().toString();
```

at the end of the `WriteArray()` method.

If you want the method to just print what it prints, then you should declare it as `void`, i.e.

```
public static void WriteArray()
```

Otherwise, you need to save all the printed lines as they are printed, e.g.

```
public static String WriteArray()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Buffer to store the printed lines

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (String lines : ArrayColors()) {

            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                lines = lines.replace("Red", "Blood");
                break;
            case 1:
                lines = lines.replace("Blue", "Ocean");
                break;
            case 2:
                lines = lines.replace("Green", "Giant");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(lines);
            sb.append(lines); // Store the printed line
        }
        System.out.println();
        sb.append("\n"); // Store a blank line
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Some other possible improvements:

- You don't need a method to access the colors, so you can put the `MyColors` variable directly in the loop, i.e. `for (String lines : MyColors)`.
- If you still want to use a method, don't declare `MyColors` at all and return the `{ "Red", "Blue", "Green"}` value directly.
- Try to follow `Java` naming conventions: only class names start with a capital letter, everything else starts with a lowercase letter, e.g. it should be `arrayColors` and not `ArrayColors`.

Comment: I see that and realized that but I need the method to be static string, so what do I return, I am a little lost. Thanks.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy PNS did not mention `static`, he meant remove the return type `String`.

Comment: Yes, the method can remain static and I have actually left it like that. :-)

Comment: Thanks, what the hell was I thinking? I was stuck in this trance that I needed a static `String` method, hence the reason for the return statement. This is great learning experience for a beginner.

Comment: No worries, we all have difficulties at start. Keep up the good work! :-)